# Did TI make a mistake in this video when they tied two mosfet gates together?

Tags: mosfet

[Automotive Front End Protection](http://youtu.be/Vq6cxmzRnyw?t=5m43s)

[image]

The two mosfets have their gates tied together, but that's all they are tied too. Will something like that work or are they missing a connection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the video they have told you to have a look at the application note.

[image]

Comment: For anyone interested, the app note is found here http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva717/snva717.pdf